# Text displayed next to images is cut short (CSS?)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having an issue with CSS in my Wordpress sites.

When I use WP's editor to make images float (not 100% sure I'm using the right terminology) to the right or left of some text, this happens when viewed from a mobile:

[image: Text is cut in css]

The text is cut.

How can I make it so that no text is displayed in there unless there is enough space for it to look good? or something like that which will fix it.

Thanks!!

p.d. Here's the code:

```
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-16" src="x" alt="x" width="250" height="283" />

.alignleft {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

It happens to all my wordpress sites so it's easily testable.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: The screenshot looks like the text has `word-break:break-all`, but it's difficult to tell without the code.

Comment: Added the code, thanks

Comment: That's a start, but it's not enough. We need a [mcve]. We need to see the problem happen ourselves!

Comment: Anyway, assuming I'm guessing correctly which website we're talking about, there's `word-wrap: break-word;` in line 46 of the CSS file, which you should remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Thanks to you guys.

You have to add this to the page's css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px)
{
img {
height: auto;
float: none !important;
}
}
```

This means, if the width of the viewing device is less than 450px, no text will be displayed alongside the image. If you want to tailor it for specific images, use their #id instead of the generic img {...

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most readable solution would be to tell the CSS to resize the picture to 100% width when on mobile.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    }
}
```

place that at the very bottom of your css file

Comment: Problem is, the image is artificially enlarged this way, so it looks pixeled.